# Java Get Path to Executable of Default Application

Tags: java, awt, desktop

Is it possible to get the path to the executable of a default application? For example, suppose I set that files with the extension ".abc" should be opened with executable ABC.exe. I'd like to use something like the following code (using `java.awt.Desktop`):

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(abcFile);
```

but is it possible to know where ABC.exe is stored in the user's computer? In my situation, `ABC.exe someFile.abc` only seems to work if I set the current directory to be that including the ABC.exe (e.g., I first have to `cd` into the directory containing ABC.exe), because it needs to find some libraries in that directory.

Comment: I think this code will use the default program for the extension type. You should not have to worry about that.

Comment: That was my hope too. I got in touch with the developer of ABC.exe. I think they need to fix something with it. Let's see if the code I shared will work after that.

Comment: Normally, when you install ABC.exe, it should set the file types it opens during the installation process. I am speaking of Windows. If it doesn't, the user must set it manually using `Open With` and `Always` from the mouse context menu. Once it is set, calling `Desktiop.getDesktop().open(abcFile.xyz)` should open using that default app.

Comment: Not easily.  You’ll need to execute some system-specific commands to find the association.  I suspect on Windows you’ll have to traverse the registry.

Comment: An easy way might be to make use of the windows start command,.Give that the file associations are setup, it will find your ABC.exe.